# Cwire terminal on Goodman furnace

Tags: wire

I have a Goodman furnace gmp075-3. Trying to install wifi thermostat. I have a C wire, but cannot find where to connect it at the furnace.

Comment: How about a wiring diagram.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the furnace as well as the furnace's wiring diagram?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to attach the c-wire inside Goodman GMP100-4 Furnace](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/158534/where-to-attach-the-c-wire-inside-goodman-gmp100-4-furnace)

Comment: Look @ https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/158534/where-to-attach-the-c-wire-inside-goodman-gmp100-4-furnace  ... there are quite a few of these same questions here but the basics is to identify the common is often looking for the transformer or a known low voltage ground point.

Comment: I'm trying to get some or even a picture to upload, but seem to be having technical difficulties  please stand by....

Comment: Well looks like attaching it to a nearby ground was the solution. Thank you all for the help and or replies.

Comment: You should write this up as an answer and accept it to close out the question.